# Not getting any text when redirecting to a text file

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I am trying to copy the content of a file using redirect operation. But after a weird block (Block elements) i am getting only a single letter and rest file is empty, though original file having complete data.

```
[root@ls-prd-server] cat /var/log/Maint/sec.log >> /tmp/logerr
[root@ls-prd-server]# more /tmp/logerr
▒▒E


















[root@ls-prd-server]
```

Please help me to understand what I missed or did wrong.

Comment: More details, please. What's a "weird block (block elements)"? Size of target file? Hexdump of source & target file? Of weird block?

Comment: Thanks RudiC for response. 
this block is MEDIUM SHADE as per ascii table and size of target file is same as orignal file 936 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `more` will interpret the special ASCII code !
So, for example, if you have in 1k file 500k of `\b` (ascii=0x07), then you log file, when more'd, will just look like it's empty.

Instead, and as mentionned in comments, use `hexdump` or similar tool to inspect the **real** content of your file.